# Search if property is match does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js

I want to return true if my property is a match in my search input. I managed to do that with my other properties from my JSON data, but in my nested data I cannot. Tried it with `for` loop and also just with `if` but without success.

this is how i get my json from DB:

```
db.query("One/docs").then(function(dataone){
  var oness = [];
  for(var i=0; i < dataone.rows.length; ++i) {
      var x = new one();
      x.fromJS(dataone.rows[i].value);
      oness.push(x);
  }
  self.OneInfos(oness);

  })
```

Maybe I'm forgetting something, I don't really know :P.

My Json data:
[image: Json img]

code 1 :

```
 function one(){
  var self = this;
  self.AssemblyName = ko.observable();
  self.Description = ko.observable();
  self.Name = ko.observable();
  self.Obsolete = ko.observable();
  self.TypeName = ko.observable();
  self.Properties = ko.observable();
  self.Implements = ko.observable();
  self.Implements.Interfaces = ko.observable();

  self.IsInSearch = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    var searchRegEx= App.instance.SearchRegEx();
    if(!searchRegEx)
        return true;  
    if(searchRegEx.test(self.TypeName())) {
        return true;
    }
    if(searchRegEx.test(self.Name())) {
        return true;
    }
    if(searchRegEx.test(self.Description())) {
        return true;
    }
    //todo - look if there is a filter for interfaces

      if (searchRegEx.test(self.Implements.Interfaces.TypeName())){
          return true;
      }   


      return false;
  });
}
```

And here is my second solution with `for` loop (it's in the same line under "todo - comment"):

```
for(var i=0; i < Implements.length;++i) { 
      var Implement = Implements[i];
      if (searchRegEx.test(self.Interfaces.TypeName)){
          return true;
      }   
    }
```

**Notice:** My implements are displayed with a select input

Comment: How are you converting your JSON to your `one` viewmodel? The way you're using both an `Implements` observable and an `Implements.Interfaces` observable is a bit weird. How about `for (var i = 0; i < Implements().length; i += 1)` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the `if (self.Implements() && self.Implements().Interfaces)`.

```
var interfaces = self.Implements();
    for(var i=0; i < interfaces.length;++i) { 
        var currentInterface = interfaces[i];
        if (searchRegEx.test(currentInterface.TypeName)){
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

Modified the code from your answer above.

I think this works as it searches through your Implements and property TypeName.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your data mapping works, since `fromJS` doesn't seem to be in your `one` viewmodel. It *is* in `ko.mapping` however, so I'll just assume you're somehow accessing it correctly.

```
var x = new one();
x.fromJS(dataone.rows[i].value);
```

According to the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), `ko.mapping.fromJS` works like so:

> All properties of an object are converted into an observable. If an update would change the value, it will update the observable.

This means `Implements` is an observable. `Implements.Interfaces` would then be undefined, but `Implements().Interfaces` would return your array.

To search the `TypeName` values of this array, you'll have to use:

```
if (self.Implements() && self.Implements().Interfaces) {
  var interfaces = self.Implements().Interfaces;

  for(var i=0; i < interfaces.length;++i) { 
    var currentInterface = interfaces[i];
    if (searchRegEx.test(currentInterface.TypeName)){
        return true;
    }   
  }
}
```

**EDITS:** Note that I've made some edits after our conversation in the comments. Seems that this question wasn't just about accessing data inside an observable, but about checking for undefined as well...

Comment: To make sure your computed doesn't throw an error when it is executed before there's any data, you could wrap the loop inside a `if (self.Implements()) { }` block.

Comment: i get undefined on the line: `var interfaces = self.Implements().Interfaces;`

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the extra check. It still assumes the data structure for all your objects is equal. I.e.: there's __always__ an `Implements` object that __always__ has an `Interfaces` array. If your data structure is irregular, you'll have to do some more undefined checks.

Comment: hmm already tried it, but i got the same error `undefined` in the line with : `var interfaces = self.Implements().Interfaces;`

Comment: What's the exact error message? Can you recreate it in a jsfiddle or other example? I don't really see how you can still get an undefined error, since you're declaring `self.Implements = ko.observable()` a few lines above. Did you remove the old code?

Comment: I didn't remove the old code,Error is : `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Ok. What's happening is this: you have a viewmodel instance that has an `Implements` object that doesn't contain an `Interfaces` array (see my comment regarding irregular data structures). You need another check: `if (interfaces) { /* for loop */ }` See updated answer.

Comment: Now i don't have an error, but it doesn't show the TypeName with that string that it has. so basically it doesnt get typename and then to return true :/

Comment: Muli, I think by know you've made some progress and should try to do some debugging yourself. If you can't get it to work, formulate a new question and link to it here. I can't really help you out based on this kind of vague description...

Comment: Thnx for trying , but this isn't really helping me cuz I'm still unable to show the the match , linke i asked how to do it